# How can I get the reference to currently active modal form?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am writing a small class for driving integration testing of a win form application. The test driver class has access to the main Form and looks up the control that needs to be used by name, and uses it to drive the test. To find the control I am traversing the Control.Controls tree. However, I get stuck when I want to get to controls in a dialog window (a custom form shown as a dialog). How can I get hold of it?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can get a reference to the currently active form by using the static [`Form.ActiveForm`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activeform.aspx) property.

Edit: If no `Form` has the focus, `Form.ActiveForm` will return `null`.
One way to get around this is to use the `Application.OpenForms` collection and retrieve the **last** item, witch will be the active `Form` when it is displayed using `ShowDialog`:

```
// using Linq:
var lastOpenedForm = Application.OpenForms.Cast<Form>().Last()
// or (without Linq):
var lastOpenedForm = Application.OpenForms[Application.OpenForms.Count - 1]
```

Comment: It seems to return null whatever I do. Any ideas?

Comment: Updated answer when no Form has focus

Comment: The controls on the form which you want to access should probably have Public access set on them, if you haven't already done that.

Comment: I used the command and i threw exception. Soltution was to place Form in the beginning of the line as . Form lastOpenedForm = Application.OpenForms.Cast<Form>().Last()

Comment: Can we get save file dialog (Already opened), like we get the forms using Application.OpenForms ?

Comment: @Jay, no, because `SaveFileDialog` is a not a `Form`, it's a native Windows dialog.

Comment: @JulienPoulin, Thanks for your reply, So is there any way to access the dialog and setting all its properties like folder location, file type, file name and most important clicking save button.....when the dialog is already opened.....?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can access controls on a pre-built dialog box; they seem all packaged together.  You may have more luck building a dialog box of your own that does what you want it to do.  Then you can access the .Controls inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if i'm wrong, though, it sounds as if you are possibly attempting to access the controls on the dialog form when it's not quite possible to.

What I mean is, `ShowDialog` will "hold up" the thread that the form was created on and will not return control to the application (or, your test class) until `ShowDialog` has finished processing, in which case your user code would continue on its path.

Try accessing or manipulating the controls from a separate thread (in this case, refactor the test driver class to spawn a separate thread for each new form that must be displayed and tested).

Comment: Yes, I created a new thread, so its not blocked. I was looking for the answer provided by @Julien Poulin

Comment: Also if you dispose the parent form the dispose method will run even with an active modal form. Its possible you may want to access the modal form then.