# Get the name of the current window open

Tags: c#

I would like to know how to get the name of a current window open in C#.
I have looked and looked and have found no solution to my question as of yet and i hope stackoverflow can help.

An example i would be thinking something like

```
String currentWindow = Window.Current.toString();
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you storing a reference to the currently open window? Also, is this WinForms?

Comment: THe currently open and focused one.

Comment: What does that mean? Is this actually for a "Window" within your application or *any* window?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/a/1127323/1080742

Answer (score 3):

Here's a snippet to achieve the desired effect that I may very well have obtained from an author at SO some time ago, so this is likely a duplicate. But non-the less here's the snippet:

```
private static string GetActiveWindowTitle()
{
    const int nChars = 256;
    StringBuilder buff = new StringBuilder(nChars);
    IntPtr handle = GetForegroundWindow();
    return GetWindowText(handle, buff, nChars) > 0 ? buff.ToString() : null;
}

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder text, int count);
```

Example usage:

```
string activeWindowTitle = GetActiveWindowTitle() ?? "Unknown Window";
```

Use `platform invoke` to invoke [`GetForegroundWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms633505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which will return the handle to the current foreground window. You can then pass the handle to the [`GetWindowText`](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDQQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms633520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx&ei=8sD1ULKBF8-7hAer_YBQ&usg=AFQjCNFvt33DuDjWTgzHGrAtMPDPqauU9A&sig2=XOS3MBSWJtv3F2-W2XnU2w&bvm=bv.41018144,d.ZG4) function which low and behold, will return the window title.

Answer (score 1):

```
[ DllImport("user32.dll") ]
static extern int GetWindowText(int hWnd, StringBuilder text, int count);
```

Import that, then use like so;

```
int CharacterMap = 256;
StringBuilder StringInput = new StringBuilder(CharacterMap);
IntPtr Window = GetForegroundWindow();
String WindowTitle = GetWindowText(CharactrMap,StringInput,Window) > 0 ? StringInput.ToString() null;
```

Didnt notice the post above.
Woops! D: